# Trying to set a field as mandatory on Oracle Applications R12

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

On oracle applications R12 I am trying to set a field as required. I have it set as required but it is not behaving as I wish. If you are creating a new form or if you are editing an old form and blank out the required field, it will tell you that you need to fill it in, which works as expected. If there is an old form that has a field that someone previously forgot to fill in, before it was required, it does not make you fill in the field. Is there any way for the required field to trigger when someone goes to press save? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the validation of that field by updating it's value to itself in order to set the record status to CHANGED, for example in the post-query trigger :block.item:=:block.item;
Alternatively, you can use the validate built-in